# Need to extract the word in between patterns

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file where it contains 30,000 lines below where I need to get the word in between 1st {}.

I tried this :

```
grep "{*}" out.txt
```

I got this as output:

```
 domain { CORE_0_RX_AcScan } -sync -module { tx20rx16_n7 }
 domain { CORE_RX_Charz_ft } -sync -module { tx20rx16_n7 }
 domain { CORE_dft0_RX_Update } -clo { CORE_0_RX_Shift } -module { i3_tx20rx16_n7 }
```

But I need the output as below (Need the words in between 1st {} ):

```
CORE_0_RX_AcScan 
CORE_RX_Charz_ft 
CORE_dft0_RX_Update
```

Comment: Try `sed -n 's/^domain *{ *\([[:alnum:]_]*\) *}.*/\1/p' out.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -n 's/^domain *{ *\([[:alnum:]_]*\) *}.*/\1/p' out.txt > results.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/NvBsU4)

Here, `-n` suppresses the default line output mode, `^domain *{ *\([[:alnum:]_]*\) *}.*` matches `domain` at the start, then 0+ spaces, `{`, 0+ spaces, captures into Group 1 any 0 or more alphanumeric or `_` chars, then again 0+ spaces, `}` and then any text to the end, and replaces the whole match with Group 1 value, and `p` prints this result only.

Or, with `awk`:

```
awk -F' *[{}] *' '{print $2}' out.txt > results.txt
```

Here, the field delimiter is a regex, see `-F' *[{}] *'`. It matches 0+ spaces, then `{` or `}` and then again 0+ spaces, only Column 2 values are output with `{print $2}`.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, tested and written with shown samples.

```
awk 'match($0,/{ [^}]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** considering that your Input_file is same as shown Input_file.

```
awk -F'domain { | }' '{print $2}' Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** With `sed`.

```
sed 's/^ domain { \([^ }]*\).*/\1/'  Input_file
```